# How to set up docker compose with monorepo structure

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, monorepo

Looking for some help setting up docker-compose for my monorepo project. I have a monorepo that has all of the code for my project, I'd like to set up two containers, one for the `db` and another for the `api`. The filetree looks like this (simplified):

```
 - /apps # Frontend stuff in here
 - /api
     - /src
     - Dockerfile
     - package.json
 - compose.yaml
 - package.json
 - yarn.lock
```

The `/api/Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:16

ENV APP /api

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR $APP

COPY yarn.lock $APP/yarn.lock
COPY ./api $APP

# Install your application's dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Expose the port your API will listen on
EXPOSE 4000

# Define the command to run your application
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

And the `compose.yaml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    build:
      context: ./  # Use the monorepo root as the build context
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
```

The `db` container is working fine, but I'm struggling to get the `api` container to work properly. I think it has something to do with the way I'm setting up the compose context or the filesystem. Specifically, I'm getting `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` errors when I run `docker-compose up --build`. Does anyone have any tips for how to improve this set up?

EDIT: By the way, when I use docker desktop to inspect the files in the container, it looks like they are there (see screenshot), yet I'm still getting this error. Note that I checked in node modules and this package *is* there. Also, if I remove the import for this package, the same error appears for another package.

```
aibible-api-1  | node:internal/errors:478
aibible-api-1  |     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
aibible-api-1  |     ^
aibible-api-1  | 
aibible-api-1  | Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@apollo/server' imported from /api/src/index.js
aibible-api-1  |     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
aibible-api-1  |     at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:852:9)
aibible-api-1  |     at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:901:20)
aibible-api-1  |     at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1115:11)
aibible-api-1  |     at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
aibible-api-1  |     at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
aibible-api-1  |     at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
aibible-api-1  |     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
aibible-api-1  |     at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
aibible-api-1  |   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
aibible-api-1  | }
aibible-api-1 exited with code 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `volumes:` section from the `api` container definition.

This block replaces *all* of the code in your image with content from the host.  In a Node image, it also replaces the image's library tree with the `node_modules` directory from the host.  Since the code is already in the image, you don't also need to inject it, and deleting this `volumes:` block is safe.

The specific error you're getting is because the image's `node_modules` directory isn't there; it's being hidden by the host mount.  Deleting `volumes:` will fix this.

---

Another thing you might try is to use `docker images` to find the image name that Compose is building, and compare

```bash
docker run --rm aibible-api-1 ls
docker-compose run api ls
```

Both of these launch a temporary container based on the image, but the second one honors most of the Compose settings.

What I expect you'll see is that the plain `docker run` shows you what's in the actual image, so you'll see the `yarn.lock` file from the project root, the `node_modules` tree generated by `yarn install`, plus things like an `index.js` file that's in the `api` directory in the original source.  With the `volumes:` mount, though, this filesystem layout is hidden, and you'll see the actual `api` subdirectory that exists on your host, and you won't see a `node_modules` directory unless there is one on your host.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! 

Would you know how to set up hot reloading for this? Something like nodemon where the container automatically refreshes when it detects changes in the source files? I think that's why I added the volumes block in the first place

Comment: I wouldn't use Docker in that scenario, just plain Node.  You could `docker-compose up -d db` to start the database container, and then point your database configuration at its published `ports:` (that is, `localhost:5433` from the host system).

Comment: Sounds good. So I can use nodemon for hot reloading for local development, then I'll use the docker compose configuration for deployments in higher environments. Is that what you'd recommend?

Comment: Yes, that matches how I normally work.